# Using Magento classes in a single PHP page

Tags: php, class, magento, mage

Some times i put some php files into my magento's root directory, which is my site's root directory too. I know this may not be best practice, but that is not the point of my question now.

For example, I have made one example.com/calc.php , a very specific calculator that does not interact with any magento data. That works OK.

Some times I did some pages with interaction with magento's data, but all through API calls (and is so slow!!!!)

```
<?php
$user='mageuser';
$pass='magepass';
$soap = new SoapClient("http://www.example.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl");
$session = $soap->login($user, $pass);
// and then cancel an order for example
$soap->salesOrderCancel($session, '100004826');
```

Is it there a way to do this including magento's classes instead of using the API to try to make things faster?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need to use the SOAP API if your scripts are on the same server as the Magento install, that's for remote interaction. You just need to access the main `Mage` object,.  Here is a good starter http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/run-magento-code-externally/

Comment: Thanks @McNab !! I will take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);

Mage::app();

$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId('100004826');
$order->cancel();
```

Comment: Can you do the full above example? Thanks !

Comment: Thanks @tim-bezhashvyly, I will try that.

Comment: Is there a documentation for the Mage class as there is for the API? I cant find anything that clear. @tim Thanks

Comment: Mage class is Magento itself. And no, it is not documented.